# данные из mysql в excel, php-excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Нужны данные из БД в MS Excel.

Алгоритм:

```
<? php>

define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "пользователь");
define("PASSWORD", "пароль");
define("", "");
 $db = mysql_connect (HOST, USER, PASSWORD);
if (!$db) {
    exit ('wrong connection');
}
if(!mysql_select_db)('бд', $пользователь)) {
        exit(DB) ;
}
mysql_querry ('SET NAMES utf8');

?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function get price() {
   $sql = "SELECT title, price, quantity, description

FROM название_табл";

   $result = mysql_query ($sql);

   if (!result) {
       exit(mysql_error());

}

   $row = array ();

    for($i = 0; $i < mysl_num_rows ($result);$i++)  {
        row[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

}
return $row;

}
```

нужно ли загружать из `classes` к `phpexcel.php` остальные файлы?

файл **price** или **index**:

```
<?php

/** PHPExcel */

require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'functions.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$price_list = get_price ();
print_r ($price_list);
```

файл при обновлении страницы не загружает xsl с таблицами. 
Подскажите что-нибудь!

Comment: А почему он их должен загружать?

Comment: нужны данные из бд в excel. Настройки + два файла так, чтобы файл xsl загружался "скачать" +  phpexcel.

Comment: Я не спрашивал, что вам нужно. Я спрашивал, почему вы думаете что ваш код будет что-то загружать? В файлах с PHPExcel есть папка `examples`, посмотрите в ней примеры работы и сделайте аналогично.

Comment: я не утверждаю, а спрашиваю. Листинг '<?php

/** PHPExcel */ ... приведен без оформления

Comment: я не утверждаю, а спрашиваю. Листинг '<?php

/** PHPExcel */ ... это фрагмент кода при выгрузке, файл загружается - данные из бд в эксель. В примере не то, что мне нужно